# How can I override part of csrf.py middleware?

Tags: django, csrf, middleware, django-middleware

I want to override `Django` `csrf.py` `middleware`; just a part of it. So I can customize the cookies (or even allow connections without cookies under specific conditions).

How could I do that??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a part in the Django documentation that explains how to [create your own middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware). Copy/modify the relevant parts of csrf.py and don't forget to modify your settings.py MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES accordingly.